# PHP/MYSQL: Obtain two items from table in join using different criteria

Tags: ios, mysql, sql

I am doing a join between tables to get a user pic from a user table about someone who comments on an article.   However, I need to get a separate picture from the user table for a different user, the person who wrote the article at the same time.  (There is a strong reason to do this in one query, as it's actually only one part of a more complex request).

Can anyone suggest how I could get two user pics from the users table during the join?  This code gives me the first user pic, the commenter's pic or upic.  But how do I also get the second user pic?

```
commments
id|comment|articleid|userid
1|great article|1|2

article
id|article|userid
1|Restaurant Openings|1

users
id|pic
1|mary.png
2|joe.png

$sql = "SELECT c.comment,c.articleid,c.userid,u.id, u.pic as upic,a.id,    
FROM `comments` c 
LEFT JOIN `articles` a 
ON c.articleid = a.id 
LEFT JOIN `users` u
ON c.userid= u.id 
WHERE c.id=1";
```

A separate query to get the author's pic for would be:

```
$sqlauthorpic = "SELECT u.pic,u.id from `users` u
WHERE u.id = 1";
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: I'm looking for something like "mary.png"   as apic in addition to joe.png as upic. This query is actually part of a larger one that returns json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `users` again this time with `article` table, since you are looking for a user that wrote the article:

```
SELECT c.comment,c.articleid,c.userid,u.id, u.pic as upic,a.id, w.pic as wpic    
FROM `comments` c 
LEFT JOIN `articles` a ON c.articleid = a.id
LEFT JOIN `users` u ON c.userid= u.id
JOIN `users` w ON w.id = a.userid
```

You can also get rid of LEFT joins because, i think there could be no comments with out an article (articleid) and no comment without userid.

Comment: Great.  Did not know you can join on same table twice. That worked like a charm.